# Objective C - Abstract Layer - Cocos 2d (other Graphic libary)

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone

I have a question about using abstract layer when use grahpic layer.

I have wrote a few game in c++ with SFML 2.0 for example. When i wrote my games a write pure virtual classes which i use. The class SfSprite inherits from pure class Sprite for example.

The advantage of using this, is that i can switch the grahpic libary very simple. I work only with the pure classes (in this example "Sprite").

Now i will develop games on IOS. So my question is:

- can i implement this pattern with protocols in objective C?
- is it recommend to implement this pattern in ios games?

Comment: question: how often do you plan on switching engines? This sounds like overengineering. You're rarely going to switch engines, and switching will still be a difficult, tedious process even with an abstraction layer. Better solution is to write the code that's independent of the engine in separate library.

Comment: For example when i have the functionality of query the keys of a keyboard by using the standard SFML Keyboard events and i want to switch to a .dll which have more functionality of query keyboard input. To switching from standard SFMLKeyboard Events and so on.. would be a nightmare..

To use a pure class Keyboard and the whole game work with this class it would be pretty simple to implement new methods or change the way how the user input will query.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can use protocols. Protocols declare interfaces; abstract classes do that too. You may use protocols for same purpose but technically they are not the same as abstract classes.
2. This pattern has nothing to do with games. There is nothing special in game programming that recommends or discourages using protocols.

Cocos2D-iphone itself makes use of protocols in many classes.

Why you have the goal of switching libraries? You'll spend more time on abstractions than on creating your game and still the task of changing libraries won't be simple. Different libraries have very different interfaces.

Will it be better to stick to a single engine for duration of one game project and then start over with another if really needs be? A possibility of supporting multiple platforms (iOS, Android, etc) is more important than switching your own code from one library to another.